# Return ObjectId from soap web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, mongodb, soap

I have 2 java application. Soap server (jax-ws) and soap client. Soap server use spring mongo and mongoDb as database. 
So, On my Server I have method that reterns all companies

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCompanies")
public CompanyList getCompanies(){
    CompanyList companyList = new CompanyList();
    companyList.companyDocArrayList = Lists.newArrayList(orgStructService.getCompanyDocService().findAll());
    return companyList;
}
```

companyList class

```
public class CompanyList {
    public ArrayList<CompanyDoc> companyDocArrayList;
}
```

And CompanyDoc

```
public class CompanyDoc{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String companyName;
//getter setter
}
```

So, when I call this method

```
 ClientService clientService = new ClientService Service().getClientServicePort();
        modelMap.addAttribute("companyList", clientService.getCompanies().getCompanyDocArrayList());
```

In clientService.getCompanies() in List I get strange objectId like  com.web.client.services.ws.ObjectId@45ee7ab1 (45ee7ab1 - this value change every refresh page)
But in database it is 5369fefa1d6e6712866daaea

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that `JAX-WS` don't know how to convert the `ObjectId` object to a `String`. I don't know how you are using your documents, but I think that you can use a `String` instead of an `ObjectId` in your `CompanyDoc` object. `Spring data` will convert your `String` to an `ObjectId` when your inserting data and vice versa.

```
public class CompanyDoc{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String companyName;
//getter setter
}
```

More info from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e1508)

> The following outlines what type conversion, if any, will be done on
>   the property mapped to the _id document field when using the
>   MappingMongoConverter, the default for MongoTemplate.
>
> - An id property or field declared as a String in the Java class will    be converted to and stored as an ObjectId if possible using a Spring
>     Converter. Valid conversion rules are delegated to
>     the Mongo Java driver. If it cannot be converted to an ObjectId, then 
>     the value will be stored as a string in the database.
> - An id property or field declared as BigInteger in the Java class will    be converted to and stored as an ObjectId using a Spring
>     Converter.